# Uninitialized local variable used?

Tags: c++, validation

having some problems with a class exercise

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int employeeNumber, grossPay, stateTax, federalTax, ficaHold;
    int totalGross, totalState, totalFederal, totalFica, totalPay = 0;


    do // do-while loop for employee number
    {
        cout << "Enter the employee number: " << endl;
        cout << "(Enter 0 to quit.)" << endl;
        cin >> employeeNumber;

    } while (employeeNumber < 0);

    while (employeeNumber != 0)
    {
        do // gross pay greater than state tax + federal tax + FICA
        {
            do // entry and validation for gross pay
            {
                cout << "How much gross pay ? ";
                cin >> grossPay;
            } while (grossPay < 0);


            do //entry and validation for state tax
            {
                cout << "How much state tax ? ";
                cin >> stateTax;
            } while (stateTax < 0 || stateTax > grossPay);


            do // entry and validation federal tax
            {
                cout << "How much federal tax ? ";
                cin >> federalTax;
            } while (federalTax < 0 || federalTax > grossPay);


            do // entry and validation for FICA holdings amount
            {
                cout << "How much FICA withholdings ? ";
                cin >> ficaHold;
            } while (ficaHold < 0 || ficaHold > grossPay);


            if (grossPay < stateTax + federalTax + ficaHold) // Message to verify taxes are not greater than pay
                cout << "State tax, federal tax, and FICA holdings cannot be greater than gross pay. Please re-enter these values." << endl;


        } while (grossPay < stateTax + federalTax + ficaHold);


        totalGross += grossPay;
        totalState += stateTax;
        totalFederal += federalTax;
        totalFica += ficaHold;
        totalPay = totalGross - (totalState + totalFederal + totalFica);

        do // do-while loop for employee number
        {
            cout << "Enter the employee number: " << endl;
            cout << "(Enter 0 to quit.)" << endl;
            cin >> employeeNumber;
        } while (employeeNumber < 0);

    }

    cout << endl << endl << "The total gross pay is: $" << totalGross << endl;
    cout << "The total state tax is :" << totalState << endl;
    cout << "The total federal tax :" << totalFederal << endl;
    cout << "The total FICA withholdings :" << totalFica << endl;
    cout << "Net pay :" << totalPay << endl << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

getting some errors for the variables on lines 95-98, eg "uninitialized local variable 'totalState'" and not really sure what to do, i already gave those variables value in the declaration before any loops, and im not sure if i can move them before anything while keeping the goal of the program

Comment: "i already gave those variables value in the declaration before any loops" No. Only `totalPay` is initialized with `0`.

Comment: thank you so much @songyuanyao, i thought you were able to list out all variables to initialize them all to the same number if they were separated by a comma, but i had it wrong. what is the proper way of initializing multiple variables like that, or is listing "int a = 0; int b = 0;...etc" the only way?

Comment: Or `int a = 0, b = 0, ...;`. IMO it's better to define one variable per line.

Answer (score 1):

The first time you use `totalState`, you're both reading and writing: `totalState += stateTax;`.  The problem is that you've never initialized `totalState`, so there's no guarantee what the value will be when you try to read it.

For the record, you have [other uninitialized variables as well](https://godbolt.org/g/YQdU6q): `totalGross`, `totalFederal`, and `totalFica`.